# Is there a way to manipulate global dataframe from a method inside a class?

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I am making a tkinter app where upon calling the function `Add_Task_Timing()`, it creates a temporary dataframe inside a method of the class `Task`. The following is format of the code:

```
# Makes a global dataframe
Task_Dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
Task_Dataframe.loc[0, 'Task_Name'] = [None]
Task_Dataframe.loc[0, 'Start_Time'] = [None]
Task_Dataframe.loc[0, 'End_Time'] = [None]
Task_Dataframe.loc[0, 'Duration'] = [None]
Task_Dataframe.loc[0, 'Team_Member'] = [None]


class Task():

    def __init__(self,task_name, start_time, end_time):
        # THIS METHOD CREATES ATTRIBUTES OF THE TASK
        self.task_name = task_name
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
        

    def Add_Task_Timing (self):  
        # THIS METHOD ADDS THE TASK TO THE DATAFRAME

        
        # column_names = ["Task_Name", "Start_Time","End_Time","Duration", "Team_Member"]

        temporary_df = pd.DataFrame()
        temporary_df.loc[0, 'Task_Name'] = [task_name]
        temporary_df.loc[0, 'Start_Time'] = [start_time]
        temporary_df.loc[0, 'End_Time'] = [end_time]
        temporary_df.loc[0, 'Duration'] = [end_time - start_time]
        temporary_df.loc[0, 'Team_Member'] = [None]
        print(temporary_df)
        
        Task_Dataframe.join(temporary_df, lsuffix='_MAIN', rsuffix='_TEMP')
        
        return Task_Dataframe
```

My only problem is that the manipulation inside the method `Add_Task_Timing()` does not happen to the global dataframe `Task_Dataframe`. For some reason the output by returning the method `Add_Task_Timing()` shows:

```
  Task_Name Start_Time End_Time Duration Team_Member
0    NaN       NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN
```

I understand that for some reason the method is not updating the values defined for the global dataframe. I have tried `concat()`,`join()`, `append()`. None seem to do the trick.

Comment: I think you need to prepend `self.` in the `Add_Task_Timing()` method. i.e.`temporary_df.loc[0, 'Task_Name'] = [self.task_name]`, `temporary_df.loc[0, 'Start_Time'] = [self.start_time]`, etc. The code you  have should be causing a `NameError` exception.

Comment: @martineau. I have already tried that. It still gives the same response.

I tried adding a column in the global dataframe `Task_Dataframe` form the method `Add_Task_Timing()` and it updated itself. For some reason, it does not respond to joining the `temporary_df` with `Task_Dataframe`.

Comment: @martineau In fact, it does the complete opposite. It only saves the numbers if I remove the `self.` prepend from `[self.task_name]`. It works just fine with [task_name].

Comment: In the `Add_Task_Timing()` function `task_name` is undefined — so I think you're mistaken (or using code different that what is in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following lines:

```
global Task_Dataframe
Task_Dataframe = Task_Dataframe.join(temporary_df, lsuffix='_M', rsuffix='_T')
```

When the `temporary_df` is:

```
  Task_Name  Start_Time  End_Time  Duration  Team_Member
0   tasking        23.0      43.0      20.0          NaN
```

The result of `temporary_df` is:

```
 Task_Name_Main  Start_Time_Main  End_Time_Main  Duration_Main  ...  Start_Time_Temp End_Time_Temp  Duration_Temp  Team_Member_Temp
0          NaN           NaN         NaN         NaN  ...                   43.0         23.0            20.0       NaN
```

I am still trying to figure out why it won't update the values in the global dataframe `Task_Dataframe`.